# How to save weights of training data from MNIST testing on tensorflow for future use?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I am facing problems with saving the training weight (W) for MNIST tensorflow example as described here. [MNIST tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html). If my understanding is correct, we need the training weight in future for other testing cases (not the MNIST testing case). I tried print W.eval() to get the weight; but it happens to provide me with a zero matrix of 784x10. How can I get the weights in an array form or in .csv format (not .cpkt)?

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar like so:

```
weight_values = session.run(W)
numpy.savetxt("myfilename.csv", weight_values, delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. Recording the answer here in case it's your issue as well / for posterity. I was printing `W` to the console and it looked like it was all zeros:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

But actually, the weights displayed in each column correspond to the first 3 and last 3 pixels in each image (upper left and lower right, I think) ... and there is no color in any MNIST image in those locations. So the weights stay zero.

If you follow Daniel Slater's advice you can see the non-zero weights in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.train.Saver().save` to save your model after it has been created. to use it simply run:

```
   tf.train.Saver().save( SESSION-NAME-HERE , "SAVE-LOCATION-HERE")
```

At some point after both `tf.Session() as SESSION-NAME-HERE:` and `SESSION-NAME-HERE.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` have been used (But before you close the session).

To Restore you can use `tf.train.Saver().restore()` with similar syntax to before:

```
   tf.train.Saver().restore(SESSION-NAME-HERE , "SAVE-LOCATION-HERE")
```

Run this After `tf.Session() as SESSION-NAME-HERE:`. This code restores previous variables used.

For futher information see: https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone used [gradientzoo](https://github.com/gradientzoo/python-gradientzoo) ?

> save, version, and share your neural net model weights

(haven't used it myself)